# Installing Carrot Creative's share button?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I feel extremely silly asking, but since I have very little experience with JQuery/Javascript, here goes. How do I install [Carrot Creative's share button](http://carrot.is/coding/social_sharing_improved)? It's apparently very easy, but all I've managed so far is to upload it on my WP's theme folder and create an empty `div`. Can someone please elaborate on the steps for me?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done? Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Following their setup [instructions](https://github.com/carrot/share-button), I [downloaded the script](https://github.com/carrot/share-button/releases/download/v0.1.1/share.min.js), added an empty div `<div class='share-button'></div>` to my index.php file, and put this in my header: `<script src='/share.min.js'></script><script>$('.share-button').share();</script>`

Comment: Were the `<script` bits added after your jQuery script? Was path/to replaced with the proper path for your setup? What shows up in the browser console when you reload the page?

Comment: I'm under the impression that I need to place `<script src='path/to/jquery.js'></script>` before `<script src='/share.min.js'>`, but I don't understand what the path would be. I'm fairly certain I have the correct path for share.min.js, though. And right now nothing is happening/showing up when I reload the page.

Comment: It sounds like you need to either obtain a copy of jQuery or use a Content Distribution Network(CDN) version of jQuery. Try adding `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>` before the share script.

Comment: Nothing! :( Just to clarify, in my `<head>` I have `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script><script src='/share.min.js'></script><script>$('.share-button').share();</script>` and `<div class='share-button'></div>` on my index.php.

Comment: If the `<script>$('.share-button').share();</script>` is in the `<head>` and executes prior to the document being ready it will attempt to attach and find nothing. Either wrap it in `$(function () {` and `});` or move the script tag so that it is just before the closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

In your footer you should have something like this

jquery.js js is the latest version of jQuery - can be found [here](http://jquery.com/)

app.js is the javascript file you will be using (copy and paste the jquery. js and delete everything in it)

share.min.js is the js that carrot provides - can be found [here](https://github.com/carrot/share-button)

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/vendor/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascripts/share.min.js"></script>
```

Make a div where you want the buttons to appear in your php file

```
<div class="social-share"></div>
```

then open up your app.js file and put this in it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   new Share('.social-share');
}); // end doc ready
```